# Regex returning complete line instead of match

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to regex out a date from a text file. This is the content:

> Storage Manager
>   Command Line Administrative Interface - Version 7, Release 1, Level 1.4
>   (c) Copyright by  Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2015. All Rights Reserved.
>
> Session established with server TSERVER: Windows
>     Server Version 7, Release 1, Level 5.200
>     Server date/time: 11/22/2016 15:30:00  Last access: 11/22/2016 15:25:00
>
> ANS8000I Server command.

I need to extract the date/time after server date/time. I have written this regex:

```
/([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})/
```

This works perfectly in regex101. See example on https://regex101.com/r/MB7yB4/1
However, in Powershell it reacts different.

```
$var -match "([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})"
```

gives

> Server date/time: 11/22/2016 16:30:00  Last access: 11/22/2016
>   15:37:19

and

```
$var -match "([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})"
```

gives nothing.

I am not sure why the match is not the same.

 Thanks for any help!

Comment: `if($var -match '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}') { $Matches[0] }`

Comment: Your 2nd `-match` sample command is identical to the 1st one. Please edit it to show the variation that truly produced nothing (or simply remove the 2nd command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator returns a boolean value showing if a match was found or not. Also, it sets the `$matches` variable with the match data (the whole match and capture group values). You just need to access the whole match:

```
if($var -match '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}') { $matches[0] }
```

See [Using `-match` and the `$matches` variable in PowerShell](http://ilovepowershell.com/2015/05/28/using-match-and-the-matches-variable-in-powershell/).

Note that there is no need escaping `/` synmbol in Powershell regexps, since this character is not special, and regex delimiters (those outer `/.../` as in JS, PHP regexp) are not used when defining a regular expression in Powershell.

Comment: Thanks!. I tried that, but then I get "Cannot index into a null array."

Comment: The error indicates `$matches` is either not an array or an empty array. Note I tested this using the text you posted, and I got a match. Please share the complete code you are using. Also, try `\s` instead of a literal space in the pattern, but I do not think it should be the culprit.

Comment: Good answer, but note that `-match` only returns a Boolean with a _scalar_ LHS (a single string). With an _array_ LHS it returns the _matching array elements_ (which are whole lines read from the file, in this case, as shown in the question).

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762775/45375), which contains many useful pointers and an effective solution, but doesn't explain **the behavior of the `-match` operator with *array* input**:

- The behavior of the `-match` operator changes **if the LHS is an *array* of strings: instead of a Boolean, the *matching array elements* are returned and the `$Matches` variable is *not* populated**. Effectively, `-match` then performs array filtering.

  - You've probably read your file content into `$var` with just `Get-Content`, which returns the lines as a string *array* rather than a single string. In PSv3+, adding switch `-Raw` reads the entire file as a single string.
  - Your regex matched (only) the 5th element of the input array (the 5th line from the file), so that element - the whole line - was returned.
- As explained in Wiktor's answer, you need to access the entries of the automatically created `$Matches` hashtable in order to access information about what the most recent use of `-match` *captured*: `$Matches[0]` contains what the regex captured as a whole, `$Matches[1]` what the first (unnamed) capture group captured (`$Matches[2]` for the 2nd one, ...), and `$Matches['<name>']` for *named* capture groups, as demonstrated in [LotPing's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40772111/45375). (`$Matches.0` is just an alternative syntax for `$Matches[0]`, for instance).
- It's better to use *single-quoted* strings (`'...'`) to define regular expressions, so that PowerShell's own string interpolation that is applied to double-quoted strings (`"..."`) doesn't get in the way.

---

When it comes to substring extraction using a regular expression, using `-replace` often allows a more concise solution:

```
$var -join "`n" -replace '(?s).*?(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}).*', '$1'
```

<sup>The extra `` -join "`n" `` step is needed to reassemble the array of lines in `$var` into a single string to pass as input to `-replace`.

The explanation below shows how to use `Get-Content -Raw` to read the entire file as a *single* string to begin with.</sup>

**Explanation:**

```
# Read the text file as a *single* string, using -Raw.
# Note: Without -Raw, you get an *array* of strings representing 
#       the individual lines.
$var = Get-Content -Raw file.txt

# Define the regex that matches the *entire* input,
# with a single capture group capturing the substring of interest.
# The regex:
#   - is prefixed with an inline-option expression, (?s), which ensures
#     that . also matches a newline.
#   - starts with .*? a non-greedy expression matching any
#     sequence of characters at the start of the input,
#   - followed by the original capture-group regex (though without escaping of / as \/,
#     because that is not necessary in PowerShell, and \d used instead of [0-9])
#   - ends with .*, a greedy expression that matches everything through the
#     end of the input.
$re = '(?s).*?(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}).*'

# Using -replace, we replace the entire input string - by virtue
# of the overall regex matching the entire string - with only 
# what the capture group captured ($1).
# The net effect is that only the capture group value is output.
# With the sample input, this outputs '1/22/2016 15:30:00', the first
# timestamp encountered.
$var -replace $re, '$1'
```

Comment: that -Raw comment is priceless. I didnt understand why my -match was returning an array instead of bool just like everyone says!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are matching several lines, it's pulling out the line that matches, to pull out the individual match from the line use the following:

```
foreach ($line in $var) { if ($line -match "([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})") {write-output $matches[0]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with lengthy REs it does make sense to use named capture groups. When splitting a RE up into several, the name stays the same. When the RE might span several lines you should use `(?smi)` and to be able to match crlf with `.` you have to get-content with the -raw option. I use \d instead of [0-9] just to save 3chars.

```
$var = Get-Content File.txt -Raw
if ($var -match "(?smi)Server date/time: (?<ServerDT>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}).*access: (?<LastAc>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})") { 
  "ServerDT  : "+$matches.ServerDT 
  "LastAccess: "+$matches.LastAc
}
```

Output

```
ServerDT  : 11/22/2016 15:30:00
LastAccess: 11/22/2016 15:25:00
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I still prefer to use .NET regex class matches method directly - it is faster, precise and verbose. If you are sure that first date is the result that you search you could use:

```
[regex]::Matches($var,'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}')[0].value
```

I personally  will put "Server date/time: " into the regex, then will remove it from the result (and parse cleared result to DateTime object if it is necessary).

```
([regex]::Matches($a,'Server\sdate/time:\s\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}').value) -replace "Server date/time: ",''
```

PS. One quick advice avoid to use var as variable name even for tests. Really bad habit.

Comment: Thanks. Using the .net classes is definetly easier and returned exactly what I needed. Thanks!